# "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed"

Tags: active-directory, ldap, samba

I mangage a Primary Domain Controller (Samba+LDAP) with 60PC. But 3-4 PC can't login to domain with error:

> The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary
>   domain failed.

56-57 PC login to domain normally.

LDAP and Samba service alway run on Server. And `MyComputer\Manage` on Client is normal:

[image]

If I power on PC and wait 1-2 minutes or try several login. I can login nomally.

Please help me fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically due to one of two things:

- Trust relationship is stale between PC and domain controller

In this case, you should unjoin and rejoin domain.

http://www.ehow.com/how_8436933_unjoin-client-domain.html

- Time is out of sync between PC and domain controller

If time difference is more than 5 minutes apart by default, authentication will fail. Fix by getting the time to the actual time on each such that they match.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307897

Hope that helps.